# Version control GitHub svn on Rstudio

Tags: r, git, github, svn, rstudio

I can type in browser on GitHub that I can see in Rstudio and vice versa if I push an edit from Rstudio and commit. Why do I still see my svn as not found under global options then? Does it matter? I am aware that my address for shows this when typing “which git" in terminal: /usr/local/bin/git

Here is the image of Rstudio global options:
[image]

Comment: Are you actually attempting to use Github with Subversion, or are you using git?

Comment: There are many types of version control systems, some distributed, some not. A very short list of examples: `git`, `svg`, `cvs`, `rcs`, and `hg`. They are not compatible with each other. Absence of one has no impact on performance of the others. If you're using github, all you need is `git`.

Comment: @Calum I am attempting to use GitHub with version control such that I van connect to it through Rstudio - which seems to be working - however svn path always shows ‘not found’. do I really need to worry about it?

Comment: @r2evans answers my question that I don’t really need svn since I have git. yet I can’t figure out what’s going on after I did some tests from terminal

Comment: also I changed the git path to /usr/local/bin/git and svn to /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn    as I found those relevant files there. Earlier I could not change these so I did a Xcode reinstall.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your problem is - you said that you were able to successfully commit and push, so what is wrong with your installation?

Comment: @Calum all I was interested in knowing is why SVN path could not be found. As it turns out I didn’t actually need it given that GIT was working fine. Given my curiosity, I found that reinstalling Xcode and changing directory of svn to the right location can now help me use version control via SVN.

Answer (score 1):

In the next link you cand find step by step how to use version control with RStudio that may be helpful.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077?version=2021.09.1%2B372&mode=desktop

I downloaded SilkSVN and did not appear on my SVN executable neither. You can find out where is located by using the next command on git:

```
where svn
```

In my case:

```
C:\Program Files\SilkSvn\bin\svn.exe
```